# Why do I need to reinstall my wireless driver on reboot?

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I installed this [driver](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux) for my USB dongle using these commands;

```
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -a rtl8812au
```

And every time I reboot, I have to modprobe them again and its generally an annoyance. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

My dongle;

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. A6100 AC600 DB Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8811AU]
```

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you just run `sudo modprobe rtl8812au` when you reboot without the three commands you are performing in your question?

Comment: You should not compile as root, just make. You need sudo for make install and modprobe.

Comment: @L.D.James I'm sorry, I didn't mean remake them, I just meant modprobe again.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I was just following the instructions provided in the github, I mean that isn't causing a problem.

Comment: It won't affect the compiling and installing of the driver.  It' just not necessary to be a super user to compile programs... only to perform an install for successful compiling.  If you're working in your personal space you will be creating files and folders that your normal account won't have access over.  This can affect your normal use of your personal space.  Depending on the integrity of some of the applications you might try to compile (by running the make) it could also possible affect other system-wide files unexpectedly.

Comment: @UsernameVF - The instructions in github are not best practices and can cause problems as suggested by James. Best practice is to use root as little as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent Ubuntu versions, there is a *dkms* package to solve just this. From the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

You should be all set.

Comment: There's an error in the dkms.conf that causes this to fail after every kernel update. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have to reinstall/recompile** the driver on every boot. You only have to `make` and `install` the module once.  If it works (as you have suggested in your question) you can add it to your module configuration to automatically be loaded on boot.

Since it's already installed, just load it.  This can be done automatically on startup.

Place the module name in the `/etc/modules` file.  These are modules that are automatically loaded at boot time.

This should be one module per line.  Arguments for the module is also accepted.

This is taken from the [modules manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/modules.5.html).

This should be your `/etc/modules` file:

```
# any other modules here
rtl8812au
```